# How can I "diff -c" with git?

Tags: git

In $VCS I make heavy use of `$VCS diff -c $N` to see only the changes introduced in revision `$N` (ie, `diff -r $N..$N+1`).

How can I do the same thing with git?

Comment: Dang, I wish I could "accept" both answers -- but since I have to chose, I'll give the points to Bombe (VonC, I hope you can live without the 15 rep).

Comment: Hahaha... good April's fool! Well done. Well... Hmmm... Ok, joke's over, now. GIVE ME BACK ME PRRRRESSSIOUSSS points!!!... ... Darn, no joke, then. Oh well, I guess I will live without those ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# git show -p SHA1_COMMIT
```

Comment: I usually prefer it because I only need to type (or paste) a single commit ID. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
git diff SHA1_COMMIT^ SHA1_COMMIT
```

With `SHA1_COMMIT` being the `SHA1` of the commit you want to inspect.
That "**[`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)**" will compare:

- the version before the commit referenced by that SHA1 and
- the commit referenced by said SHA1.

As mentioned in the [source code of the builtin-diff.c](http://github.com/git/git/blob/442dd42d6d4903640b0dc5561481a77c88dcea90/builtin-diff.c), the syntax parsed is:

```
static const char builtin_diff_usage[] =
"git diff <options> <rev>{0,2} -- <path>*"
```

Comment: Technically, they only need to be "commitish" objects.  So, you can also say "git diff HEAD~2 HEAD" or "git diff HEAD origin/master".

Comment: @Pat, you are right. My answer was made for the specifics of the question ("see only the changes introduced in revision $N"), but you can indeed specify any two commits.